Random lattice always has trivial automorphism group?
In example 2.5 of a paper [LS17]  written by Lenstra and Silverberg, it is written that “Random” lattices have $Aut(L) = \{ \pm 1 \}$, I guess the 'Random' here refers to the distribution in Siegel's paper [Sie45]. I would like to know where this conclusion can be found.
